# I have a jquery autocomplete entry that I want to add a down arrow image inside of

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery autocomplete entry that I want to make look more like a "combobox".  I set it up so that when the user clicks into the entry it will blank out and do a blank query to show all possible matches.

I want to add a special "down arrow image" inside of the autocomplete entry so that the user knows to click on that arrow like it is a select box arrow.  How do I stick this image inside of the entry to make it looks like a select/combo box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a CSS trick, you'll have to set a background image on the input box (or at least nothing default), and create one button that is aligned to the input (the arrow), to make it look like a continuation of the input. Google is your friend.

Comment: This kind of works, but it doesn't give a browser native or clickable look to that arrow.  The css style I used was:
.autocomplete {
background: transparent url("arrow.jpg") no-repeat;
background-position: right bottom;
}

Comment: @MikeN: just look at their upper-right button http://mac.appstorm.net/

It should be pretty self-explanatory.